# How can I view the commands history for users who use sudo -i

Tags: sudo

I would like to know if there is available bash_history or something when a user use sudo -i. Their commands don't appear in their .bash_history file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, `sudo -i` will start the login shell of the target user (`root` by default). History in that shell will be stored according to that shell's settings. If `root`'s login shell is bash, it will be saved to `$HISTFILE`, which is `~/.bash_history` by default. So look for a `.bash_history` in `root`'s home directory (`/root`, usually). Or inspect their login shell defaults and rc files to determine where (if) it stores history.